# Applying touchstart on dynamically generated divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this swipe feature that I found off the internet, and it works really well with a single div. I'm trying to incorporate it into my own web app that has generated divs and I'm wondering how I could differentiate each divs.

I'm very new to javascript and I don't understand all the ways to structure code very well. I was able to do this with `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave` by using the `$(this)` keyword to handle each events specifically. 
Except this code I found, I wasn't able to structure what's familiar to me and to get it to work.

Here is my HTML. This div will be generated by php.

```
<div id='generatedDiv'>

  <div class='swipeArea'>

  <div>

  <div class='option1' style='display:none'>
      <input id='first'>
  </div>
  <div class='option2' style='display:none'>
      <input id='second'>
  </div>

</div>
```

So what im trying to do is, when user swipes up, `option1` will be set to `display:block`, on a swipe down the same for `option2`.

Here the javascript I found that I want to incorporate

```
var el= document.getElementsByClassName('swipeArea');

for( var i=0; i < el.length; i++){
swipedetect(el[i], function(swipedir){
    if(swipedir =='up'){
        $('.option1').css('display','block');
        $('.option2').css('display','none');
    }else if(swipedir=='down'){
        $('.option1').css('display','none');
        $('.option2').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('.option1').css('display','none');
        $('.option2').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

This is as close as I have gotten, and the results will affect all the divs at the same time.

***additional code from the swipedetect function

```
function swipedetect(el, callback){

var touchsurface = el,
swipedir,
startX,
startY,
distX,
distY,
threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
allowedTime = 300, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
elapsedTime,
startTime,
handleswipe = callback || function(swipedir){}

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
    swipedir = 'none'
    dist = 0
    startX = touchobj.pageX
    startY = touchobj.pageY
    startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
}, false)

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
    distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
    if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for swipe met
if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
            swipedir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
        }
    }
    handleswipe(swipedir)
    e.preventDefault()
}, false)
}
```